# How to inlcude httpd apache config into docker container: as image or as volume mount?

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, apache2

I'm often in situations where it's not clear if a configuration should be either included into the docker image, or just shared into as mounted volume.

Like as follows, where I want to share my server config into a `httpd apache2` container.
The config itself will hardly every chance once running. Is it better to include the config directly into the image, or share it as volume mount from host?

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
...
COPY server.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/sites/server.conf
...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:2.4
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - server.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/sites/server.conf:ro
```

Of both is valid:
is it in general better to have only one single images (thus share config by volume), or better having multiple images that includes the different configs?

Especially regarding that usually you have at least a `test` and a `production`  configuration that is different.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid options, I normally mount it with a volume. In case I need to make changes to the file, I would rather make them on the host machine, restart the container and commit my changes, instead of making the changes in the container as well as on the host so that I can commit them to the repository.

Comment: If both is valid, then the question is: is it better to build two different images (when including the conf into the image)? Or is it better to build only one single image, and share the different config as volume?

Comment: @membersound - that depends on what your objectives and concerns are which are not present in your question. Opinions vary. For a production scenario, self-contained images are better (repeatability and history). For development, a single image is useful and helps with fast prototyping.